# Как правильно сделать полигоны в html

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon

Всех приветствую. Тут недавно столкнулся с SVG графикой, необходимо сделать одну фигуру. Вроде бы сделал, но столкнулся с рядом нюансов. На фото будет представлено как должно быть, и отдельно кодом, как есть. 
Читал мануалы разные, перепробовал многие вещи, почему-то не выходит так, как надо.

[image: Дано изображение]

Тут вроде смотришь, всё легко и просто. Однако простыми силами css такую фигуру адекватной не сделать.
Начинаешь делать через полигоны, выходит то, что ниже я вставлю...

[image: Не правильное отображение]

Как убрать лишнюю толщину у левого верхнего угла?
Как скруглить остальные углы?

Код прилагается.

```css
.big-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.promo-box {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-box">
  <div class="promo-box">
    <svg width="312" height="472" style="fill: #f2f2f2; stroke: #1698d9;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-width="9">
        <polygon points="0 50, 50 0, 312 0, 312 472, 0 472"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="promo-box">

    <svg width="312" height="472" style="fill: #f2f2f2; stroke: #1698d9;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-width="9">
        <polygon points="0 50, 50 0, 312 0, 312 472, 0 472"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="promo-box">

    <svg width="312" height="472" style="fill: #f2f2f2; stroke: #1698d9;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-width="9">
        <polygon points="0 50, 50 0, 312 0, 312 472, 0 472"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
    <div class="promo-box"> 
            <svg width="312" height="472">
    <path d="M0 50 L50 0 H 312 V 472 H 0 Z" fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="8" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>

    <!-- <polygon points="0 50, 50 0, 312 0, 312 472, 0 472"/> -->
</svg>
        </div>
        <div class="promo-box">

            <svg width="312" height="472"  style="fill: #f2f2f2; stroke: #1698d9;" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-width="9">
    <polygon points="0 50, 50 0, 312 0, 312 472, 0 472"/>
</svg>
        </div>
        <div class="promo-box">

            <svg width="312" height="472"  style="fill: #f2f2f2; stroke: #1698d9;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-width="9">
    <polygon points="0 50, 50 0, 312 0, 312 472, 0 472"/>
</svg>
        </div>
```

Пробовал так, но ситуация не изменилась...

Comment: Очень похоже на тестовое задание отсюда)):
https://funbox.ru/vacancies/html-css-developer

Comment: оно и есть :) Но, так как печаль досада, не пойму с чем связана ошибка)

Answer (score 4):

Используйте `path` для рисования линии, и установите `viewBox` чтобы линия не обрезалась:

```css
.big-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.promo-box {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-box">
  <div class="promo-box">
    <svg width="312" height="472" viewBox="-5 -5 332 482" style="fill: #f2f2f2; stroke: #1698d9;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-width="9">
        <path d="M0,50 L50,0 L292,0 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 L312,452 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 L20,472 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 L0,50 L50,0" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  
  <div class="promo-box">
    <svg width="312" height="472" viewBox="-5 -5 332 482" style="fill: #f2f2f2; stroke: #1698d9;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-width="9">
        <path d="M0,50 L50,0 L292,0 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 L312,452 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 L20,472 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 L0,50 L50,0" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  
  <div class="promo-box">
    <svg width="312" height="472" viewBox="-5 -5 332 482" style="fill: #f2f2f2; stroke: #1698d9;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-width="9">
        <path d="M0,50 L50,0 L292,0 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 L312,452 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 L20,472 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 L0,50 L50,0" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Объясните, пожалуйста, с чем связано сие действие? 
После написания поста, я уже сделал через viewbox, только с другими параметрами

Comment: @Gwai, с чем связано указание viewBox? С тем что если рисовать линий между точками 0,0 и 100,0 (т.е. на границе) шириной 9 пикслей, то по 4 пикселя окажутся за границой (цент сопадает с границой)

Answer (score 2):

`clip-path` в помощь:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.card-thumb {
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 25%, 25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 25%, 25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}

.c-1 {
  background: #1886bd;
}

.c-2 {
  background: #d91667;
}

.card img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0px 7px 7px 7px;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 25%, 25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 25%, 25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-thumb c-1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533738699159-d0c68059bb61?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=0bb9888db1d270eab08c77f41120dfca&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-thumb c-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518064711538-4e27e702c706?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d27c0369f194434f87a058060024cf0d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: на мой взгляд твой ответ самый лучший: работает во всех современных браузерах, плюс полная адаптивность (+)