# Как реализовать border у прямоугольника с отрезанным углом?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Как реализовать неровный border?
Фон неровный поэтому треугольник через псевдоэлемент не сделать.
clip-path использовать не могу,надо поддерживать ie11

```css
.a2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 15px, #58a 0) right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a2">
</div>
```

Comment: Я когда-то задавал такой вопрос, предлагаю взглянуть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644310/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899775/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2-html/900119#900119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через псевдоэлемент не сделать, а через два псевдоэлемента можно)) :

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.a1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 3px solid #000;
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
  border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #58a 0%, #58a 89%, #000 89%, #000 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 43px;
}

.a1:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 43px;
  width: 154px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 0 0 7px 43px;
  border-top: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
  border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

.a1:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 157px;
    width: 43px;
    top: -3px;
    right: -3px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 0 43px 12px 0;
    border-top: 3px solid #000;
    border-left: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 3px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.a2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 3px solid #000;
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
  border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #58a 0%, #58a 89%, #000 89%, #000 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.a2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 158px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
}

.a2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 158px;
  width: 3px;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
}

.a3 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background: #58a;
  border-radius: 0 0 43px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="a1"></div>
<div class="a2"></div>
<div class="a3"></div>
```

Comment: А если border-radius?

Comment: Через linear-gradient! Хитро) +

Comment: @Александр не совсем понятен вопрос, но на всякий случай добавил пару вариантов.

Comment: @kizoso на просторах интернета иногда такие вещи градиентами творят, что дух захватывает))